# Destroy JsonWebToken on logout request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, jwt

I want to destroy the JWT whenever user sends the logout request to the app.

First of all, I am not storing JWT in the database so I can not delete that and I am also not using cookies or sessions. Is JWT stored on the client side? If so how can I destroy the JWT and invalidate the user's requests after logging out of the app.

The token middleware:

```
module.exports = middlewares = {
  authenticateToken: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      if (!req.headers["x-access-token"]) {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: "Key x-access-token not found",
        });
      }

      if (req.headers["x-access-token"] === "") {
        return res.status(401).json({
          error: "Token not found",
        });
      }

      const token = req.headers["x-access-token"];
      const data = jwt.verify(token, keys.JWToken);
      if (!data) return res.status(401).json({ error: "Invalid token" });
      req.data = data;

      next();
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
    }
  },
};
```

Here's how I generate token on the registration and login requests:

```
const payload = { id: new_user._id };
const JWToken = jwt.sign(payload, keys.JWToken, { expiresIn: 31556926 });
```

Comment: I personally use cookie or session for storing jwt and I think it's one of the usual ways. So in order to make the user log out. You should send another cookie to the client for example "loggedout" to replace the jwt.

Comment: Can you please post the example of cookie or session. Because I have never used it so I literally have no idea how to use it. (connect-redis example)

Comment: ```const logout = (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("jwt", "loggedOut", {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 10 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? true : false,
  });
  res.status(200).json({ status: "success" });
};```

Comment: this is the controller that handles logout with a GET request. So basically I replace the "jwt" cookie with any random string("loggedOut" in my case)

Answer (score 0):

The code provided is from the server, hence I don't know how its being saved on the client side, usually it is done using localhost, cookie or session. But you have mentioned that you are not using cookie or session, hence there is a chance that you are using local storage to store the jwt token. You can check your local storage on chrome by going to developer options -> Application -> Local Storage. You may find your token by how you named it, you can access it and delete by localStorage.removeItem("name of your token");